# Laravel MySQL whereIn Closure Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Can anyone help to explain why one of the following Laravel queries works and the other doesn't?

The first that works:

```
$array = ( 1, 2, 3 ,4 );
$query->whereIn( 'status_id', $array );
```

This works as expected. However, when I try and pass a function to build my array:

```
$query->whereIn( 'status_id', function() use ( $statuses ){
    $status_array = array();
    foreach( $statuses as $status ){
         $status_array[] = $status->status_id;
    }

    return $status_array;
});
```

I get the following error:

> General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select * from `jobs`  where
>   `status_id` in (select *))

I have checked to see that the array I am building in the closure is the same as the array that works, and it is. Am I missing something fundamental regarding whereIn() and it's closure functions? Can I even pass a closure to whereIn()?

Comment: What happens if you do "return array(1, 2, 3, 4)" from the function - does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a closure in `whereIn()`, Laravel will think that you will be doing a sub query. Hence you see another `select` inside your `in` in your error message.

You'll need to parse your array of values before passing to the `whereIn()`

```
foreach ($statuses as $status) {
     $status_array[] = $status->status_id;
}

$query->whereIn('status_id', $status_array);
```

---

**Extra:** See reference to Laravel source.

[Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L661):

```
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    ...

    if ($values instanceof Closure)
    {
        return $this->whereInSub($column, $values, $boolean, $not);
    }
}
```

which calls `whereInSub()`:

```
protected function whereInSub($column, Closure $callback, $boolean, $not)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotInSub' : 'InSub';

    // To create the exists sub-select, we will actually create a query and call the
    // provided callback with the query so the developer may set any of the query
    // conditions they want for the in clause, then we'll put it in this array.
    call_user_func($callback, $query = $this->newQuery());

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'query', 'boolean');

    $this->mergeBindings($query);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, with a combination from Shift Exchange's answer above. Accepted this answer as you've given me a good explanation as too why things weren't working out as I expected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

As a related answer, instead of running a loop to generate your list - [just have Laravel do it for you](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects)

```
 $status_array= DB::table('status')->lists('status_id');
```

then use it

```
 $query->whereIn( 'status_id', $status_array );
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a lovely little function and saves the extra foreach :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your function returns an array like this one:

```
[ 0 => status_id_value_0,
  1 => status_id_value_1, 
  ...
]
```

Try to return an `array_values($status_array)` to check it.

Anyway, try this one too:

```
$query->whereIn( 'status_id', 
                 array_values(
                     array_map(
                         function($pos){return $pos->status_id;},
                         $statuses
                     )
                 )
               );
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert comma separated value to array before passing to whereIN.

and this is also good for any dynamic content

```
    foreach ($statuses as $status) {
         $status_array[] = $status->status_id;
    }
    $query->whereIn('status_id', $status_array);
```